# Extract Keywords from text php

Tags: php

I am trying to extract relative keywords from description input which use Wysiwyg, with multi language english/arabic… using the following function but its not doing the task I want. Have a look the function I am using:

```
   function extractKeyWords($string) {

     mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
     $stopwords = array();
     $string = preg_replace('/[\pP]/u', '', trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/iu', '', mb_strtolower($string))));
     $matchWords = array_filter(explode(' ',$string) , function ($item) use ($stopwords) { return !($item == '' || in_array($item, $stopwords)
 || mb_strlen($item) <= 2 || is_numeric($item));});
     $wordCountArr = array_count_values($matchWords);
     // <p><p>

     arsort($wordCountArr);
     return array_keys(array_slice($wordCountArr, 0, 10));   }
```

Comment: What result are you getting? What result are you expecting? Please edit your question and add examples.

Comment: Already solved thanks ! @Reed

Comment: Glad you got it working! It's good practice on SO to post the answer to your own question if you beat others to it, in case somebody else visits and needs help with a similar problem. Your question could still be cleared up a little, too, but an answer might clear things up too.

Comment: @Reed Just posted the answer ;) Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

figured it out ! Thanks

```
function generateKeywords($str)
        {
            $min_word_length = 3;
            $avoid = ['the','to','i','am','is','are','he','she','a','an','and','here','there','can','could','were','has','have','had','been','welcome','of','home','&nbsp;','&ldquo;','words','into','this','there'];
            $strip_arr = ["," ,"." ,";" ,":", "\"", "'", "“","”","(",")", "!","?"];
            $str_clean = str_replace( $strip_arr, "", $str);
            $str_arr = explode(' ', $str_clean);
            $clean_arr = [];
            foreach($str_arr as $word)
            {
                if(strlen($word) > $min_word_length)
                {
                    $word = strtolower($word);
                    if(!in_array($word, $avoid)) {
                        $clean_arr[] = $word;
                    }
                }
            }
            return implode(',', $clean_arr);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This one seems very nice and comprehensive https://www.beliefmedia.com.au/create-keywords

Just make sure to change this line

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}0-9 ]/', ' ', $string);
```

to

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}0-9 ]/u', ' ', $string);
```

To support other langages (e.g Arabic)

And also better to use `mb_strlen`

Answer (score 0):

If the string is in html format you can add the
`strip_tags($str);`

Before

`$min_word_length = 3;`